# Confusion in finding Effective Atomic Number of a complex

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

In finding EAN (Effective Atomic Number) of metal in complexes, I came over one compound:
$\ce{[(CO)2RhH2Rh(CO)3 Cl]^+}$

Here the hydrogen are shown as bridging atoms and we are supposed to calculate EAN of individual rhodium atoms
The main problem is that hydrogen has a single electron, then how can it form a bridging bond?

I thought, maybe hydrogen is giving electron to one of the rhodium atoms and other rhodium is giving lone pair to hydrogen, but this doesn't seem like a good argument.

Comment: In this case, think of the hydrogen as a hydride anion and add four electrons, two from each hydride ligand, to each rhodium

Comment: Ok @Kanghun Kim . will we take O.N of each Rh same like = 4/2 =+2? But, the molecule is not symmetric

Comment: [Effective_atomic_number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_atomic_number) has two different meanings: one that is the effective nuclear charge of an atom, and one that calculates the average [atomic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_number) (number of protons found in the nucleus) for a compound or mixture of materials.  Do you by chance mean rather [oxidation state/number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidation_state) ?

Comment: H atoms are bridging atoms in the molecule $\ce{B2H6}$. Single electrons may form a bridging bond.

Comment: B2H6 is known to be electron-precise and to obey the octet rule- this can only happen if each of the bridging hydrides is counted ss a 2e- donor to each boron atom.

Comment: @Poutnik I mean number .

Comment: @Hannah Good, but what number? Or the question is just a side question without direct relation to the EAN of the complex ?

Comment: @Poutnik valence electrons actually, the heading says 18 e- rule -EAN and we are supposed to calculate EAN of Rh in the complex

Comment: I see, so the 3rd meaning. :-)